# vhost on ubuntu with xampp does not work

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu and I installed xampp. If I enter 'localhost' in my browser the correct XAMPP page appears.

Now I wanted to change the htdocs folder into '/home/adam/Web/mydomain.de'.
Therefore, I uncommented 'Include etc/extra/httpd-default.conf' in /opt/lamp. p/etc/httpd.conf and I added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/adam/Web/mydomain.de"
    ServerName mydomain.de
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.de
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.de-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.de-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

to /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf .

If I enter "www.mydomain.de" in my browser I get:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

But there is a index.php file and the folder Web and all subdirectories have chmod 777 and I am also set as the owner of these files - why is it not working? Also, when I change the code to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
        ServerName mydomain.de
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.de
        ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.de-error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/mydomain.de-access_log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

then "www.mydomain.de" returns the expected XAMPP page again. So for some reason it really looks like my folder does not have read permission - even though it has the right permission. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/adam/Web/mydomain.de"
    ServerName mydomain.de
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.de
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.de-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.de-access_log" common

    <Directory "/home/adam/Web/mydomain.de" >
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```